# KDE Neon Missing Icon after installing aplication

Tags: icons, kde-plasma-5, kde-neon

I just done installing my first KDE Neon.

But after that, when I install aplication always not showing icon on menu.
Its look like this:

[image]

I already tried change icon to another icon then back it to breeze icon, but it not works.

Can you help me, how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I just need to restart it and icon back to normal after that :D